# MS SQL Server: View with all parents of a child

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following mapping table which contains pairs of parent/child ids:

```
parent_id | child_id
   3      |     5
   5      |     4
   4      |     9
   6      |     7
   7      |     8
```

I need to create a view for this table which would list all parents of a given child. Using the example above, the resulting view should look something like this:

```
parent_id | child_id
   3      |     5
   3      |     4
   5      |     4
   3      |     9
   5      |     9
   4      |     9
   6      |     7
   6      |     8
   7      |     8
```

The view would have a row for each parent (direct or indirect) of a certain id, the more parents, the more rows. One could assume that there are no loop in this table.

I'm not sure how to approach this as I've looked into recursive selects and loops but I'm unsure how to incorporate them into a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select t.parent_id, t.child_id
      from t
      where t.child_id = @child  -- not needed if you want all
      union all
      select t.parent_id, t.child_id
      from cte join
           t
           on t.child_id = cte.parent_id
    )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: That gives the correct number of results but following the example above, for instance `9` is present 3 times in the resultant table but every time the `parent_id` is the same - `4` which is its direct parent.